# Azure Devops Custom Upstream Feed for Maven (Jetbrains or others)

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

we are trying to get an additional upstream feed for our project-scoped feed in azure devops.

The maven repo that we want to include is the jetbrains maven feed and some self-hosted nexus.

Currently, we have the choice between premade set of repos (central, google etc.)

But we struggle to add some custom maven repo. When we select "custom repository", it seems like we can add only node repos. Is there some implicit security guideline that we miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Artifacts does not currently support custom upstreams for package types other than npm. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hey, thanks though. At least we can Stop searching now :)